# Change request.user to a proxy instance

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have created a proxy model for `django.contrib.auth.models.User` which has several methods I'd like to use in my views and templates.

In views I can do

```
appuser = AppUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

but assigning it to every template seems to be an overkill. Is there a way to change `request.user` to a proxy model instance? I'm already considering writing a middleware for this, but if there is a shortcut for this, that would be great.

I'm using latest (1.7.6) Django with Python 2.7, if that counts.

Changing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not an option, as I already have severaly migrations, and the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) says:

> If you intend to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you should set it before
>   creating any migrations or running `manage.py migrate` for the first
>   time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by proxy model, but is using a custom user class not enough for your needs? Then you would have any method  anywhere you have a user instance. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @user640916 See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: Not a good method but you can monkey patch the `User` class to add a method that returns a proxy object. You can then use `request.user.get_appuser()` in your views or `user.get_appuser` in your templates.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work applitation-wide, or I may misunderstood you. Will doing `User.get_appuser = lambda(…)` in my `models.py` make `user.get_appuser` available from a view where I don't import anything from myapp?

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the comments, you should set your proxy as the custom user model by setting AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to your model. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: This is not an option for me. The documentation says “If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time”. I have already done that, this proxy model was created much later than the first migration.

Comment: Hmm, that advice is really for people who are changing the model completely, I'm not sure how relevant it is for proxy models since you're not changing the actual tables.

Comment: The problem (as I see it) is that if I change the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, the migrations in `django.contrib.auth` won’t be executed, thus, my migration chain will break at the beginning. Didn’t have the time to test it yet, though, but I will come back with the result as soon as I can.